# grails service inside a package

Tags: grails, groovy, service

I'm pretty new to grails and spring
Me created a `service` like this

```
services\com.mypackage\MyService
```

where

```
class MyService {
    static transactional = true

    def serviceMethod(params) {
         println "params:"+params
    }
}
```

Then when in my controller

```
controller\com.mypackage\mycontroller
```

Then in its action I tried to access like this

```
def myaction= {
        com.mypackag.MyService myService //also used def myService
        myService.serviceMethod(params)
        render(view: "otherpage")
    }
```

But it show the following error :(

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method serviceMethod() on null object
```

it cannot make the object of myservice.

```
myService shows null
```

What mistake i have done?

It will be very helpful if anyone provide me some **good simple links and tutorials for using service with grails**
Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One mistake you have done.
You are declaring that `myService` inside your `myaction` closures. Where it should be done in the `controller` **outside any of your methods or closures**.
You can access your service methods using your service object (here myService) inside any of your methods or closures

So change like this
In your `controller\com.mypackage\mycontroller`  declare your service first

```
def myService
```

Then you can access it in any `closures`

```
 def myaction= {
        myService.serviceMethod(params)
        render(view: "otherpage")
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your directory hierarchy does not correspond to you packages. You should change the directory hierarchy for your service to:

```
services\com\mypackage\MyService.groovy
```

and make sure you add the following at the top of `MyService.groovy`

```
package com.mypackage

class MyService {
  // .....
}
```

Similarly, change the directory hierarchy for your controller to

```
controller\com\mypackage\MyController.groovy
```

Then to get a reference to your service inside your controller

```
// add the correct package statement
package com.mypackage

// rename the controller and the mycontroller.groovy file to MyController
class MyController {

  // this will be injected by Spring (it must be named with a lower-case 'm')
  def myService

  def myaction= {
    // use the service inside your action
    myService.serviceMethod(params)
    render(view: "otherpage")
  }
}
```

Comment: Update your post with details of your new configuration and the error you're getting and I'll try to help

Comment: One mistake was there. I declare that myService inside myaction. Now I changed and works fine. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1) I'd read the [Grails User guide on Services](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/8.%20The%20Service%20Layer.html)

2) I'd make your services using the command line tools grails provides as it will save you putting things in invalid directories (`com.mypackage` as a folder name is going to give you nothing but trouble), and it will make sure you have the correct package declarations at the top of your groovy files

Comment: Thanks tim_yates me working in IntelliJ IDEA 10.0.2 there i create package and all by right button click on service. You are asking me to remove that package ?